# From "competo" to "competition"

Tags: etymology, metamorphoses

I was looking at the origin of the English word "competition" and it seems to come from the Latin *[competitio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/competitio#Latin)*.

Yet, this word comes from the Latin *[competere](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/competitio#Etymology)*, which is the present infinitive of *[competo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/competo#Latin)*, that itself means

> I meet; I coincide; I agree

I fail to see how *competo*, which could well be translated as "I cooperate", lead to another word which means "I compete". In many senses, there are almost antonymous!

Answer (score 2):

The particular meaning of *competo* needed here is 'seek simultaneously' — as the competitors in a foot-race try at the same time to reach the winning tape. In the alternative sense that is making you confused, the verb's subjects have a common goal which both wish to see attained.

The word *competitor* has in Latin exactly the same, restricted meaning as the English and has nothing to do with co-operation.

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find about such meaning of _competo_? Or what is the same, do you have some references that support that statement?

Comment: @luchonacho. A proper dictionary is a good place to begin, e.g. http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcompeto

Comment: Most Latin dictionaries are based on Freund's Latin-German *Wörterbuch*, and have much the same attestations (but not to say an exact correspondence). Any will provide exemplary usages, and the better ones are on line. I prefer Smith's, but Lewis and Short's is popular. Smith gives two sources for *competitor*, to correspond with the English meaning 'rival', 'competitor': Cic. Off 1.12.38  _si est inimicus, aliter si competitor (cum altero certamen honoris et dignitatis est, cum altero capitis et famae)_ and Liv. 6.41 _qui certos sibi uni honores inter dimicantes competitores aequum censeat_.